# Error - not a statement when I have already defined the variable I use

Tags: java

It's giving me the error "not a statement" and I can't understand why.

Here's what the error is telling me:

```
CoolNumbers.java:17: error: not a statement
    for(num; num <= meme; num++){
        ^
```

Here's the (now updated) code:

```
    import static java.lang.System.*;

public class CoolNumbers
{
    int num = 6;
    int isCoolNum;
    int meme;

    public int meth(int meme){

    for(num; num <= meme; num++){
        if (num % 3 == 1 && num % 4 == 1 && num % 5 == 1 && num % 6 == 1){
            isCoolNum++;
        }
    }
            return isCoolNum;

    }

}
```

Comment: for all of those comparisons, you want == instead of =, as = is the assignment operator.

Comment: It's to check whether a number is a cool number (remainder of 1 when divided by 3, 4, 5, and 6).

Comment: I suggest you learn about variable scope and operators first.

Comment: Kevin, I just realized my mistake and have repaired it, but the original error is still there.

Comment: Show your updated code please. On which line is it throwing the error?

Comment: the error is showing on line 17, I have updated my post with the error

Comment: Grant, when you want to reply specifically to someone in a Comments discussion you should "tag" them to be sure they see you're reacted. Type @ followed by their name, for example @KevinW. and they'll get a mail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your for loop:

```
for(num; num <= meme; num++){
```

Should probably be:

```
for(; num <= meme; num++){
```

I assume `num` does not need an initial value (since you already gave it one when you declared it). If it does, you need something like:

```
for(num = 0; num <= meme; num++){
```